# One of the terms of the development of $(\frac{2}{x}+x)^{10}$, with $x \neq 0$, does not depened on x. Which term is it?

Tags: calculus

> [image]

I tried with the first term (using Newton's binom):

$$^{10}C_0(\frac{2}{x})^{10}\cdot x^0 = (\frac{2}{x})$$

Then I tried the last one:

$$^{10}C_{10}(\frac{2}{x})^{0}\cdot x^{10} = x^{10}$$

My book states the solution is B. How do I solve this?

Comment: The "middle" term of the binomial expansion is $\binom{10}{5} \left(\frac{2}{x} \right)^5 x^5 = \binom{10}{5} 2^5 = 8064$.

Comment: Are you rather asked "What is the numerical coefficient of the constant term?"

Comment: @DJohnM No, I copied the question verbatim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the binomial formula, 
$$(x+y)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k}x^ky^{n-k}$$

By applying this identity, 
$$\left(\frac{2}{x}+x\right)^{10}=\sum_{k=0}^{10} {10\choose k}\left(\frac{2}{x}\right)^kx^{10-k}=\sum_{k=0}^{10} {10\choose k}2^k x^{10-2k}$$

If $k=5$, this term of the polynomial does not depend on $x$ since $x^0=1$. This means that the coefficient you are searching for is

$${10 \choose 5}2^5=252\cdot 32=8064$$

The answer is (B).

Answer (score 1):

One term contributes with negative exponent, the other, positive.

$^{10}C_{5}(\frac{2}{x})^{5}\cdot x^{5}=\dfrac{10!}{5!5!}2^5\dfrac{x^5}{x^5}=8064$